# Lead with Companies

Tags: master-detail

I want to create a tab called Company that will be connected with the Leads.
More specifically if a company has multiple leads I want to categorize them.

Lets say that the company has

- Company Name
- Company website

And that Tab is connected with the Leads Tab somehow and when I go to Company I can see all the leads associated with that company.

Is there a way to do this?

Please advise,

Darko

Comment: Hello Darko,  Is there a specific Reason you have to create a Tab for This ?

Comment: @user40138 thanks for writing. Yes there is a specific reason for this. I want to categorize my leads to be in Companies, because my company needs this step. We have many leads that are in one company and I want them to be categorized. When I go in the lead I want to see a related list showing the company and when i go to company i want to see a related list with the leads. Thanks